# how do i check if execv function faild or succeeded?

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

i got an assignment to write a simple linux shell ,
this is the code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc,char argv[])
{
char *token;
char command[50];
char tmp[256];
char *arg_command[]={"",0};
int pid,status,flag=0;


char *path = (char*)getenv("PATH");


while(1) // run always
{
    printf("\n");
    printf(getenv("PWD")); //print current dir 
    printf(": ");
    gets(command);

    if (strcmp(command,"exit")==0) //check for exit command
    {
        printf("bye\n");
        break;
    }

    strcpy(tmp,path);
    token = strtok(path,":");

    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        arg_command[0] = command;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid>=0)
        {
            printf("\npid is:%d\n",pid);
            if (pid==0) // child process is invoked
            {

                strcat(token,"/");
                execv(strcat(token,command),arg_command);
                exit(0);

            }
            else //parent process 
            {

                wait(&status);
                if(status==0)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("fork faild");
        }

        token = strtok(NULL,":");   
    }

    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("no files or folders match this command\n");
    }

    strcpy(path,tmp);   


}
    return 0;
```

}

my question is how do i know whether execv was able to execute the command or not 
because i want to output an error when ever the user entered a wrong command.
i also have a flag but because i cant check execv i cant use it .

Answer (score 0):

Like most Unix/POSIX functions, `exec`* return an error code (-1) if they fail. `errno` will then tell you why it failed.

In fact, if they ever return, then something went wrong. Otherwise, the current process is replaced which means no code after is ever execute (`exit(0)` in your case).